# Noty Jquery Plugin Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the Noty plugin and have setup my page as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/js/noty/layouts/topRight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/js/noty/layouts/topLeft.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ecomm/application/assets/js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>

    <script>

        var n = noty({
            text: 'NOTY - a jquery notification library!',
            animation: {
                open: 'animated bounceInLeft', // Animate.css class names
                close: 'animated bounceOutLeft', // Animate.css class names
                easing: 'swing', // unavailable - no need
                speed: 500 // unavailable - no need
            }
        });



    </script>
```

Which however doesn't display any notification and returns:

```
.
jquery.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
xa  @   jquery.js:3
n.extend.css    @   jquery.js:3
sa  @   jquery.js:3
ta  @   jquery.js:3
Ja  @   jquery.js:3
n.fn.extend.show    @   jquery.js:3
n.fn.(anonymous function)   @   jquery.js:3
b.show  @   jquery.noty.packaged.min.js:1
a.notyRenderer.show @   jquery.noty.packaged.min.js:1
a.notyRenderer.render   @   jquery.noty.packaged.min.js:1
a.notyRenderer.init @   jquery.noty.packaged.min.js:1
window.noty @   jquery.noty.packaged.min.js:1
(anonymous function)    @   index.php:18
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce your error?  Or make a JSFiddle or something.

Comment: @JackZelig Yes, this is a problem with Noty...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try at your code but was able to manage 2 demos for your purpose.

1. Using Noty.js

http://jsfiddle.net/otd7huq4/6/

2. jGrowl (notifications with jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/mmw8N/15/

**Sample-**

```
$.jGrowl("Hello world!");
```

As per my earlier experience, I think jGrowl is much more simpler & beautiful.